# Is there a Recovery Key for encrypted external drives?

Tags: external-disk, filevault

When you encrypt your startup disk with FileVault, macOS gives you a recovery key. Does macOS also create one for external drives? If not, would it be possible to make it create one?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

When you use FileVault, you are encrypting the entire *boot* volume, not just a single volume or folder.

If you're looking for something where you can encrypt a *removable* volume (i.e. USB drive), take a look at [VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Choosing%20Passwords%20and%20Keyfiles.html) where it allows you to have both password and keyfile authentication.  It's also cross platform which is definitely a plus.